# Can I make SST/Sysview notify me when job is completed?

Tags: mainframe, mvs

I am monitoring a job using Sysview on our glorious IBM mainframe. Can I somehow make the tool or the mainframe just notify me once the job is done, or will I have to sit around and poll it for hours?

Comment: Notify you in what manner?  I presume the NOTIFY= parameter on your JOB statement isn't sufficient to your needs, so what would you like to have happen when the job is complete?

Comment: I must commend you on the use of the adjective "glorious". Beyond that, I will second cschneid with NOTIFY=?

Comment: I guess I should add: I am the new generation of mainframe devs, so I use RDz from a Windows workstation most of the time. A text message on the TSO will most likely go unnoticed.

Comment: Can you explain what it's SST/Sysview or point a link describing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a last step to your batch job that does an [IEBGENER](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=utilities-iebgener-sequential-copygenerate-data-set-program) to send an email or text message via an [OUTPUT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=reference-output-jcl-statement) statement pointed to by the SYSUT2 DD.  Use the [MAILTO](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=statement-mailto-parameter) parameter of the OUTPUT statement.

I admit this is pretty clunky.  You might want to communicate your desire to the IBM Rational folks, either as a marketing requirement or a [SHARE requirement](http://www.share.org/p/cm/ld/fid=131).

Comment: Can you explain what are the requirements to use the MAILTO parameter?
I think that you probably need to have a SMTP channel in place at least.

Comment: I'm sure there must be something handling the SMTP traffic, but I'm not sure if that's just built into the TCP/IP started tasks or not, sorry.  The Sysprogs take care of making things work at that level.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **SMTP** utility in JCL and have the data to be present on email in corresponding DDs. I'm not having syntax here but do lemme know if you need.